# Scrapy Crawl (referer: None) ['partial']

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new at scrapy and python. I am trying to scrap data from `www.freepatentonline.com`. Here is my code.

```
class FreePatentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'freepatent'
    allowed_domains = ['freepatentsonline.com']
    search_value = 'laptop'
    start_urls = [f'https://www.freepatentsonline.com/result.html?sort=relevance&srch=top&query_txt={search_value}&submit=&patents_us=on']
    
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    def request_header(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls, callback=self.parse, headers={'User-Agent':self.user_agent})


    def parse(self, response):
        for data in response.xpath("//table[@class='listing_table']/tbody/tr/td/a"):
            title = data.xpath(".//text()").get()
            related_link = data.xpath(".//@href").get()
            absolute_url = f"https://www.freepatentsonline.com{related_link}"
            yield{
                'title':title, 
                'related_link':related_link,
                'absolute_url':absolute_url
            }
```

I am getting

```
2023-01-17 20:00:41 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-01-17 20:00:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.freepatentsonline.com/result.html?sort=relevance&srch=top&query_txt=laptop&submit=&patents_us=on> (referer: None) ['partial']
2023-01-17 20:00:42 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Debug Crawl Status is 200 but I don't know why it is not scraping data.
can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request_header` method isn't doing anything so you can remove that, and it looks like the table you are trying to scrape doesn't have a `<tbody>` element, which is why your xpath is failing and you are getting no results.

Try this:

```
class FreePatentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'freepatent'
    allowed_domains = ['freepatentsonline.com']
    search_value = 'laptop'
    start_urls = [f'https://www.freepatentsonline.com/result.html?sort=relevance&srch=top&query_txt={search_value}&submit=&patents_us=on']
    
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

    def parse(self, response):
        for data in response.xpath("//table[@class='listing_table']//td//a"):
            title = data.xpath(".//text()").get()
            related_link = data.xpath(".//@href").get()
            absolute_url = f"https://www.freepatentsonline.com{related_link}"
            yield{
                'title':title, 
                'related_link':related_link,
                'absolute_url':absolute_url
            }
```